# Entity Framework 4 INNER JOIN help

Tags: entity-framework, entity, inner-join

Can anyone tell me how to write the following query in Entity Framework 4.0? "Blogs" and "Categories" are my entities. The query basically returns me the list of categories and the number of blogs that are in that category.

```
SELECT b.CategoryId, c.Value, Count(b.Id) AS [Count] FROM dbo.Blogs b
INNER JOIN dbo.Categories c ON b.CategoryId = c.Id
GROUP BY b.CategoryId, c.Value
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work (LinqToEntities):

```
var categories = from c in oc.Categories
                 select new
                 {
                     CategoryId = c.Id,
                     c.Value,
                     Count = c.Blogs.Count()
                 }
```

This will give you a list of category ids and values and for each category id you get the number of blogs in that category.

EDIT: To give an answer to the question in your comment: this isn't possible in LinqToEntities but you can do it in Entity SQL.

```
var results = new ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord>(
    @"SELECT y, COUNT(y)
      FROM MyEntities.Blogs AS b
      GROUP BY YEAR(b.CreatedDate) AS y", entities).ToList();
var nrBlogsPerYear = from r in results
                     select new { Year = r[0], NrBlogs = r[1] };
```

In the Entity SQL query, you should replace `MyEntities` with the name of your context.

EDIT: As I just found out through a comment by Craig, grouping by year [*is* possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx) in L2E so you can write your query like this:

```
    var nrBlogsPerYear = from b in oc.Blogs
                         group b by b.CreatedDate.Year into g
                         select new { Year = g.Key, NrBlogs = g.Count() };
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly. I didn't knew we can do "select new" without defining a class which has those properties.

Comment: Another quick question if you don't mind. How do I write a L2E query which returns the Year and the number of blogs for that year. Blog.CreatedDate has the date info and I'm looking for something like 

Year Count
-----------
2010  12
2009  45

etc.. so I can display in UI like 2010 (12), 2009 (45) .. Thank you!

Comment: You can do the year grouping in L2E as well. [L2E supports the Year property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx)

Comment: Cool, didn't know that. Thanks. I'll update my answer with this new info.

Comment: And how does one use this in EntityDataSource?

Answer (score 2):

If you have navigation properties in your entities, you can do that :

```
var cats = from c in db.Categories
           let count = c.Blogs.Count()
           where count > 0
           select new
           {
               CategoryId = c.Id,
               Value = c.Value,
               Count = count
           };
```

If you prefer to use an explicit join, you can do it like that :

```
var cats = from c in db.Categories
           join b in db.Blogs on c.Id equals b.CategoryId into g
           select new
           {
               CategoryId = c.Id,
               Value = c.Value,
               Count = g.Count()
           };
```

Comment: This is great. But My case I can't fine `b.CategoryId`. If I use `b.CategoryID` it is showing error that the property is not exsits. I can avoid the compile time issue by providing `b.Category.Id`. But in this case, the result is not equivalent of Inner Join (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896266.aspx). My question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506333/foregin-keys-are-not-mapped-in-the-entity-framework-version-4-0

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from p in B.Products
            join c in B.Categories  on p.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID 
            orderby c.CategoryName,p.ProductName 
            select new 
            {
                c.CategoryName ,
                p.ProductName,
                p.ReorderLevel  
            };

GridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
GridView1.DataBind();
```