# Foregin Keys are not mapped in the entity framework (Version 4.0)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I created an edmx file using an existing database. I am trying to implement [JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896266.aspx). But there is some while I tried to create a query similar in to that. 
There is a compile time issue.

> CodeBox.FB.DataAccess.PlayerTeamSeason' does not contain a definition
>   for 'PlayerID' and no extension method 'PlayerID'  accepting a first
>   argument of type 'CodeBox.FB.DataAccess.PlayerTeamSeason'  could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?!

And I can able to see the corresponding classes which are based on tables. But I found that in Mapping Details window, there are some columns which does not have equivalent fields/properties and I found that these are forgein key feilds .
I found so many questions in SO , but I didn't found a solution for my issue. 
I found this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896266.aspx) 
When I tried to Join with two tables, I cannot join with the foreign key.

But I can join something like this

```
 var query =
        from contact in contacts
        join order in orders
        on contact.ContactID
        equals order.Contact.ContactID into contactGroup
        select new
        {
            ContactID = contact.ContactID,
            OrderCount = contactGroup.Count(),
            Orders = contactGroup
        };
```

`order.Contact.ContactID` like this I can able to make join.

But I am expected something like the following query.

```
var query =
        from order in orders
        join detail in details
        on order.SalesOrderID equals detail.SalesOrderID
        where order.OnlineOrderFlag == true
        && order.OrderDate.Month == 8
        select new
        {
            SalesOrderID = order.SalesOrderID,
            SalesOrderDetailID = detail.SalesOrderDetailID,
            OrderDate = order.OrderDate,
            ProductID = detail.ProductID
        };
```

`order.SalesOrderID equals detail.SalesOrderID`. When I tried using my edmx I generated , I can't found the corresponding foreign keys in my entities.

This is the query I expected to write . 
But it is having error on `PTS.PlayerID` and `PTS.TeamID`

```
var pl2 = from PTS in dataContext.PlayerTeamSeasons
                      join P in dataContext.Players on PTS.PlayerID equals P.ID
                      where PTS.TeamID == 3
                      select P.ID;
```

If I changed the query to this then it will works fine.

```
        var pl3 = from Pts in dataContext.PlayerTeamSeasons
                  join P in dataContext.Players on Pts.Player.ID equals P.ID
                  where Pts.Team.ID == 3
                  select P.ID;
```

May I know why this is happen.

Kindly see my screenshot.

[image: Mapping Details]
Thanks

Comment: Your object has a property named 'PlayerId', and your error message indicates you're trying to use a property named 'PlayerID' (capital 'D') - does that help?

Comment: The Entity Framework can only correctly generate the relations (and navigatin properties) if they are also established in the DB structure as well.Please check that you have the Primary Keys and Foreign Keys correctly defined in your database. Also, check the properties of the primary key fields in the entity model that they are correctly marked with `Entity Key == true`.

Comment: What you generated your entities did you thick the checkbox for including foreign keys in the model?

Comment: yes I have checked. The primary keys have property `Entity Key == true`

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I think when I created first time, I didn't checked the checkbox. But I tried to update the model from database . At that time I  checked it. Is there any way to map the foreign key fields without creating a new edmx file?